# How to make a click event on a specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image gallery (slider), like this:

```
<div class="imgWrap current">

    <img src="image1" />

</div>
<div class="imgWrap">

    <img src="image2" />

</div>
<div class="imgWrap">

    <img src="image3" />

</div>
```

Then I have some events:

```
$(document).on('click', '.current img', function(){

    $('#anotherDiv').click();
});
```

That all works fine.

I tried now to make an event to click only the div (not the image), something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', $('div:not(img)'), function(){

    $('#anotherDiv2').click();
});
```

My scenario is:

I click on image to go to the next image, if I click outside from the image then they go back to the gallery.

The `div imgWrap` filled the whole page and I can`t change the HTML code.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stop propagation from the image

```
$(document).on('click', '.imgWrap img', function (e) {
    console.log('img');
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$(document).on('click', '.imgWrap', function (e) {
    console.log('div');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRtLk/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in this case

```
$('.current img').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```